# Update failing (index failed to download)

Tags: 12.04

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.
Here's the message I'm getting in terminal:

```
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/au.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-backports_main_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How to solve this?

Comment: To which version are you upgrading to?

Comment: I wasn't upgrading. Just running updater. The problem occurred over a number of days. I used to get a little red icon on the top right next to the little envelope telling me no update check had been run. Today I did a manual check for updates again, run the updates and all went well. I noticed that one of the updates was for Updates Manager.

Answer (score 1):

That simply means that the index file it downloaded did not match the expected checksum hash. That could simply be because it downloaded incorrectly (corrupted/truncated) or for whatever reason the original archive on the server was not created correctly and its currently of no use to anyone.

This does happen occasionally and can be considered "normal". Try again in a few hours when a new index file is generated as new updates are applied to the repository and you will likely download it without any problem this time.

If it occurs regularly, consider changing mirrors.

Comment: Thanks for response. The problem occurred over a number of days. I used to get a little red icon on the top right next to the little envelope telling me no update check had been run. Today I did a manual check for updates again, run the updates and all went well. I noticed that one of the updates was for Updates Manager.